# Node.js server to webapp connections

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas, github-pages

I'm running a game which contains a server.js backend (which is hosted and run on my localhost), and the frontend is on a github website. The github page connects to the server on my localhost through the config which points to 127.0.0.1. I realize that I will be able to play this from my localhost this way, but will other people be able to?

Basically the index.html connects to the visitor's localhost to look for the running server.

A visual representation (sort of):

[nullwalker.github.io/index.html] ----> [localhost(127.0.0.1)/server.js]

What should I do to allow myself to play from the computer that's hosting the server backend as well as others being able to play?

Comment: You should really host the game backend elsewhere. For security and performance you probably don't want to make your local machine a web server. Look into a free Heroku account or something.

Comment: Joyent has a nice comparrison chart of node hosting providers: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to host it in a live environment. There are ways via port forwarding to use your computers ip (gateway) to allow others to connect, however typically ISP's will try to stop you from using your dynamic IP statically. Safest bet is to launch a cheap VPS and host it there.

http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

This article seems to explain port forwarding well enough.

As for the VPS, you can find extremely cheap ones really easily, if you do not expect a lot of players it should be fine, if you expect more then using your own connection is dangerous.

Comment: I am able to get a static IP through [NoIP](http://noip.com/), but won't that mean I can't play while other people can?  Other than that, I don't have a credit card because I'm only 15, so could you point me to a way to get it hosted for free?

Comment: You can find prepaid credit cards in most convenience stores, that's what I did at that age, if its a cheap VPS as long as you have it backed up there is very little harm in using a prepaid visa. Also as long as you change the IP its looking for to the static IP, then you should be able to use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

unless they have the same server running on their localhost, no. And they almost surely don't. You should get a host (digitalocean.com is very popular and good, but there are many others), and then run it there and connect to that instead of localhost